# animation with transition don't start in unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a fighting game and I don't know where I should integrate my animation in the script. I have 4 actions : Idle , Walk , Kick One , Kick 2 . My script is for phone controllers , where should I put the animations? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzQrO.jpg and this are some settings to them https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd1zF.jpg

```css
 public class Move : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private Animator anim;
 
     public float moveSpeed = 300;
     public GameObject character;
     private Rigidbody characterBody;
     private float ScreenWidth;
     private Rigidbody rb2d;
 
     public bool isDead = false;
     public Vector2 jumpHeight;
     public int jumpCount = 0;
     internal static object instance;
 
 
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start()
     {
         ScreenWidth = Screen.width;
         characterBody = character.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb2d = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb2d.freezeRotation = true;
         anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
 
         if (isDead) { return; }
         if (jumpCount < 3 && (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)))  //makes player jump
         {
             GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode.Impulse);
             jumpCount++;
         }
         jumpCount = 0;
         int i = 0;
         while (i < Input.touchCount)
         {
             if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
             {
                 RunCharacter(1.0f);
 
             }
             if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
             {
                 RunCharacter(-1.0f);
             }
             ++i;
         }
     }
 
 
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
         RunCharacter(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
 #endif 
 
     }
 
     private void RunCharacter(float horizontalInput)
     {
         characterBody.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
 
     }
  
 
 
 }
```

Comment: Make an animator, link up all the animations, and then call them where you need to trigger them

Comment: I. add this in void update but doesn't work if (i >= Input.touchCount)
            {
                anim.ResetTrigger("Movement");
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetTrigger("Movement");
            }

Comment: well, depends a lot where you put it, and why i should be >= touchCount,  is the trigger in your animator called "Movement"? its case sensitive.. it really does depend on what exactly you did...